Determinant of Jacobian of camera model
Consider a simple pinhole camera model as commonly used in computer vision:
$$
x_{\rm{pcs}} = f x_{\rm{ccs}} + p_x\\
y_{\rm{pcs}} = f y_{\rm{ccs}} + p_y
$$
where ccs represents the 3D camera coordinate system, and pcs represents the 2D pixel coordinate system.
The Jacobian is
$$
J = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{f}{z} & 0 & -\frac{f}{z^2} \\
    0 & \frac{f}{z} & -\frac{f}{z^2}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now, consider that we have a world coordinate system in addition to the camera coordinate system. We have a rotation matrix that transforms a direction vector from the world coordinate system to the camera coordinate system. The combined transform will be $T = J R$, which is a 3x2 matrix.
Now, consider a point in the ground plane of the WCS, $\mathbf{X} = (x, y, 0)$. It follows that $T \mathbf{X}$ is only using the 2x2 matrix consisting of the first two columns of $T$, which we may call $T_2$.
Can the determinant of $T_2$, the first two columns of $J R$, be negative? And if so, what is the intuition for that?

I think the determinant will be positive or negative depending on which side you're looking at the plane from. Eg something in the plane will look reflected if you flip the camera around to the other side.
